# How can I get the type from the result of a callback action?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I'm not really sure how to express what I need to do in terms which has made searching for a solution very hard. I've also tried reading the Typescript docs but I couldn't find anything related to what I want. I have this condensed code example of what I'm trying to do:

```js
function test(
  name: string,
  actions: () => {/* I need something else here */}
) {
  return actions()
}

const foo = test('foo', () => ({
  bar() {
    console.log('foo.bar')
  }
}))

foo.bar() // Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
```

Is it possible to get Typescript to understand that `bar()` should be available on `foo` in this case?

Comment: Just declare your test function as. function test<T>(name: string, actions: () => T) {
  return actions();
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [typescript generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

```
function test<T>( //Generic type T
  name: string,
  actions: () => T // Callback return value
): T { // Whole functions return value
  return actions()
}

const foo = test('foo', () => ({
  bar() {
    console.log('foo.bar')
  }
}))
```

Check it out in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po%20rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc%20VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBZJcWCoCjwTL6VAAHhwAD4ABSgEAAcVRP3UaBa3kUJU4DGQ%20WuqEonGYvBFYhpdM4BVA7IAlKAALys7xcsAAYQY0Gg0h6iScBLIXh0xvYSnVkpwoAA3vqIJh4O5cdTafThJbCTa7UoSoHrYq-SqNYoAL7BBAqmjJeAYLVoRnsgDkKfgWf4Gu1uvZLoVZrIhdLJRKicEXsgAWg8GY2dzAXLWfVCvjsfVXcUbfLGoA3EA)